# impersonal pronoun "it"

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

1. To exercise regularly is important.
2. Exercising regularly is important.
3. It is important to exercise regularly.
4. It is important exercising regularly.

Is the fourth sentence grammatically correct? Can a gerund be a subject (like the example 4)?

Comment: KannE's suggestion for (4) uses cataphoric referential _it_; its referent is _exercising regularly_. However, example (3) uses 'dummy _it_' which has no referent; it is merely a device allowing subject extraposition ('To exercise regularly is important' is grammatical but sounds rather rarefied).

Comment: Why use 4? If it’s used, for example in informal. speech, it would be “It’s.” In writing it makes the reader wonder if it’s a typo, a non-native speaker doing the writing, an attempt to be chatty or friendly, laziness, or whatever.

Comment: (4) is a different structure from the others. It's grammatical, but since extraposition doesn't normally work on gerund subjects, the subject  _it_, ia **not** impersonal and needs a noun of some sort to be put in apposition with it. The final gerund is not the subject, but it's in apposition with the subject. It could just as easily come before _it_. The others are normal.

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *To exercise regularly is important.*
>
> [2] *Exercising regularly is important.*
>
> [3] *It is important to exercise regularly.*
>
> [4] *It is important exercising regularly.*

[1]-[3] are fine. Note that the extraposition construction in [3] has the non-referential dummy pronoun "it" as subject.

[4] as written is not acceptable. Gerund-participial clauses are found extraposed, but only under sharply limited conditions. [4] is in fact a 'right dislocation' construction where, unlike in [3] the later element does provide a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun.

I haven’t seen a detailed attempt to say when gerund-participials are OK in extraposition, but certainly some cases sound fine. But I remember that in early work in generative grammar it was said simply that extraposition could not apply to gerund-participials.

For those reasons, I'd say that [4] requires a comma, and a pause in speech after "important". This phonological difference makes it a different construction called 'right dislocation'. Unlike the non-referential pronoun "it" in the extraposition construction in [3], the later element in [4] does provide a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun.